# Grails alters my table using not null instead of null

Tags: grails

I'm developing a personal project with grails in order to learn this powerful tool.
I have encountered this problem when adding two new fields (x,y) to my domain class "Post":

```
class Post {

   long id;
   Date creationDate;
   String text;
   byte[] image;
   Style style;

   long likeCount;
   long dislikeCount;

   User owner;

   //coordinates on the wall
   int x;
   int y;

   //this is probably to remove
   static hasMany = [judgment : Judgment];

   static constraints = {
      text(nullable:true, maxSize:5000);
      image(nullable:true, maxSize:1000000);
      creationDate(nullable:true);
      x(nullable:true);
      y(nullable:true);
   }
}
```

I added x and y after I create some data (Post records) on my postgres database.
But when I run-app in grails console this error comes up:

```
| Error 2012-03-04 12:04:23,670 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  -  Unsuccessful: alter table post add column x int4 not null
| Error 2012-03-04 12:04:23,672 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - ERROR: column "x" contains null values
```

this is very strange because i declared in constraint x,y to be nullable.. so why grails try to alter my table declaring x and y to be not null?

Answer (score 4):

They're primitive `int` fields, so nullable doesn't make sense. You can't store a null value in the class instance, and if you have a null value in the database there's no sensible default conversion to an `int` value. You may consider 0 a sensible value for null, but 0 and null aren't equivalent in general.

If you want to allow null values for primitive numbers (`int`, `long`, etc.) or for `boolean` use the non-primitive Object classes `Integer`, `Long`, `Boolean`, etc. Another problem with primitive types is validation. Since they default to 0 (or `false` for `boolean`) you can't know whether the user chose 0 or `false` or if they didn't make a choice at all and you just have the default values from the constructor. So making them non-primitive leaves them `null` and you can know whether they made a choice or not.

Also, unrelated - you don't need to declare the `id` field, since Grails adds one for you anyway. And lose the semicolons ;)

Comment: you are very right, thanks very much! Do you think is it better to use always non primitive values; suppose that I have to change the database schema and add new fields.. using non primitive types should avoid this problem because they will default to null for existing records.